# AWS-Amplify with Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Following [this tutorial](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=uiTQL7Ne8rY) from AWS.

This looks awesome but I am running into some (newbie?) issues:

a. In 17:14 I don't get an option to name my project it goes straight
    to the next set of questions shown.

b. In 25:09 - when I do the amplify push, there is nothing under Category, Resource name Operation or Provider Plugin. Needless to say, nothing gets created on the Cognito side in AWS.  Only the S3 bucket was created -but due to (I think) a) it has funky name.

Did anybody else run into this issue? What am I missing? 
 *Note: I have done the configure, and the S3 Bucket is getting created but it seems like the amplify-cli is behaving different for me when compared to the video.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question---in case anybody else runs into this issue:

(a) is still an issue.  In the case of (b) the way I fixed it was to do an additional step: amplify add hosting - and then amplify push. When I did that the Cognito user pool was also created.﻿

Feels like the CLI will be very useful, but is still a little rough.